# How to correctly work with derived immutable class?

Tags: python, class, overriding, derived-class, immutability

I got some difficulties in writing a simple unit converter using derived class of build-in type `float`.

- attempt 1:
  I try to return a new copy of the instance, instead of `change the state of it`. However, I could not manage that.
- attempl 2
  I try to change the value of `self`, but it destroy atrribute `baseunit`, so `AttributeError` raised.

Another thing is that I really want to know is that how I can implementing the algebra without loss the class type, e.g. `a = Unit(km/s, 1) * 10` returns a instance of Unit as `print a  # 10 km/s`, instead of a float `10.0`. So I can further convert it using `a.to('m/s')`, then `print a  # 1e4 m/s`

Thank you I advance!

### EDIT

I modified my code according to your advise, with right using of **new**.
It partially works, as I can obtain the converted instance of class Unit and pass it to a variable. This is somewhat enough. However, Is there a way that could make the change *on site*, i.e. let the returned instance substitude my original one?

And again, If I try to do the business in another way, i.e.

```
    self /= self.conv[target]
    self.baseunit = target
```

It throws out AttributeError because `self` now is just a plain float. I guess I should define a function that override algebra operators so that `baseunit` won't lost. But How?

---

code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

class Unit(float):
    """provide a simple unit converter for a given quantity"""

    baseconv = {'length': np.array((1e-10, 1e-6, 1e-2, 1., 1e3),
                                    dtype=[('A', 'f'),
                                        ('um', 'f'),
                                        ('cm', 'f'),
                                        ('m', 'f'),
                                        ('km','f')]),
                'speed': np.array((1e3, 1., 1e-2, 1e-10,),
                                dtype=[('km/s', 'f'),
                                        ('m/s', 'f'),
                                        ('cm/s', 'f'),
                                        ('A/s', 'f')]),
                '1': np.array((1.,), dtype=[('1','f')])}

    baseunit = None

    def __new__(self, baseunit='1',num=1.):

        return super(Unit,self).__new__(self, num)

    def __init__(self, baseunit='1', num=1.):
        """set up base unit"""

        self.baseunit = baseunit

        for _key,_val in self.baseconv.items():
            if baseunit in _val.dtype.names:
                utype = _key
                break
        else:
            raise TypeError('Unit not defined: {:s}'.format(baseunit))
        self.conv = np.array(tuple(np.array(self.baseconv[utype].tolist())
                                / self.baseconv[utype][baseunit]),
                            dtype=self.baseconv[utype].dtype)

    def __str__(self,):

        return '{:e} {:s}'.format(self, self.baseunit)

    def to(self,target):

        if target in self.conv.dtype.names:

            return Unit(target, self / self.conv[target]) ! not work


        else:
            raise TypeError('Invalid converter: {:s}->{:s}'
                            .format(self.baseunit, target))


if __name__=='__main__':
    u_test = Unit('km/s')
    print u_test   # 1.0000 km/s
    u_conv = u_test.to('cm/s')
    print u_conv  # 1e5 cm/s
    print u_test  # 1.000 km/s
```

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: Not sure if this is contributing to your problem, but you're misusing `__new__`.  The first argument to `__new__` is the *class*, not the instance, so when you set `self.baseunit` and so on, you're setting those variables on the class.  `__new__` should only do what's needed to return the instance.  Then do that instance initialization in `__init__`.  You can't just squash `__new__` and `__init__` into one method.

Comment: I edited my question. Now they are more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `__new__` to create (and return) the instance. The immutable part is `num`, so that needs to be baked into the instantiation.

The remainder of the initialisation should be left for `__init__`. Something like this

```
def __new__(cls, baseunit='1', num=1.):
    return super(Unit, cls).__new__(self, num)

def __init__(self, baseunit='1', num=1.):
    """set up base unit"""

    self.baseunit = baseunit

    for _key,_val in self.baseconv.items():
        if baseunit in _val.dtype.names:
            utype = _key
            break
    else:
        raise TypeError('Unit not defined: {:s}'.format(baseunit))
    self.conv = np.array(tuple(np.array(self.baseconv[utype].tolist())
                            / self.baseconv[utype][baseunit]),
                        dtype=self.baseconv[utype].dtype)
```

Comment: I modified the code according your guide and now it throws out 
    `self.baseunit = baseunit`
    `NameError: global name 'baseunit' is not defined`